# Expectation under Cauchy distribution

Tags: integration, trigonometry, probability-distributions, expected-value, hypergeometric-function

I recently discovered this relationship but I cannot understand why it holds.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{1+x^2} \, dx = \frac{\sin(\pi\alpha/2)}{\sin(\pi\alpha)}$$
when $0<\alpha<1$.

As we already know, the pdf of standard Cauchy is given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ so the left hand side of the equation above can be interpreted as the expectation of $X^\alpha I\{X>0\}$ with $X$ being standard Cauchy.

I tried with Mathematica and this equation seems to hold. I just really want to see why. Thanks.

Comment: Some solutions with beta integrals and complex contours come up via Approach0 [(link)](https://is.gd/dWghAX)

Comment: You have a [Mellin transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) of $\frac1{x^2+1}$, so try using [Ramunajun’s Master Theorem](https://www.ssmrmh.ro/2020/06/09/application-of-ramanujans-master-theorem-rmt/) or another strategy.