# Integral of a rational function with varying exponents

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, constants

Find the **exact value** of the following integral, where $r,s \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ 0<r<s$.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{r-1}}{1+x^s}dx$$

I have looked 3 cases:
Case 1: $0<r,s<1$
Case 2: $0<r<1<s$
Case 3: $1<r<s$
Under all 3 cases, the integral is convergent from 0 to $\infty$. The area under the curve varies with r and s. How can I find the "exact value" of the integral?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: See [this case for $s=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394775/expectation-under-cauchy-distribution). The integral may be a [lerch transcendent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$I=\int\frac{x^{r-1}}{1+x^s}dx$$

$$x^s=t \implies x=t^{\frac{1}{s}}\implies dx=\frac 1 s t^{\frac{1}{s}-1} \,dt$$
$$I=\frac{1}{s}\int \frac {t^a } {1+t}\,dt \qquad \text{where} \qquad a=\frac r s-1 <0$$

Under the conditions $r,s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 <r <s$, the definite integral
$$J=\int_0^\infty \frac {t^a } {1+t}\,dt$$ is pretty well known.